# Accidentally deleted home directory on Linux, how to recover?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, delete, rm

I accidentally deleted my home directly from terminal with `rm -rf`. Later, I tried to recover the deleted contents using `foremost` and `testdisk`. I couldn't recover the content and there were some contents recovered but damaged.

Anyone have better way to restore deleted content? **I want to restore my content with old directory structure in home directory**.

Any **3rd party software** or anything. Any help or suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Restoring from your backups is always easiest, but how are we to know what backup strategy you use?

Comment: When you say restore, what backup file do you have?

Comment: Hi @guiverc, thank you for the response. I didn't have any backup at that time. I was taking backing using timeshift. But before that I deleted everything accidentally

Comment: @darth_epoxy, thank you for the response. I have no backup. I want to restore deleted data.

Answer (score 2):

Data recovery, and in particular on the ext file system linux uses, is complex. You did the best you could with tools like `testdisk`. Any more comprehensive recovery would probably require professional services.

This is why maintaining a good backup of your own user data is of paramount importance. An operating system is downloaded easily, and installed in less than an hour. Your user data, however, are unique and cannot be recovered once lost. Hence, make sure to have a good backup, because that is the only realistic option to fully recover accidentally deleted data.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. I was taking backup using timeshift but before that this accident happen. Can you suggest any professional way to restore deleted files?

Comment: Of course not. I am not a professional data recovery specialist. Note that timeshift is for backup of system configuration, not for backup of user data.

Comment: Sure. I'll keep that in mind. Thanks